# Which command line should I use to get date of specific git commit?

Tags: git, version-control, commit

So I have git hash (for example 123abc4 or full), what should I type in my terminal to get the date when this commit was published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git show 123abc4
```

[`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) will give you the date, author, description and file diffs.

As discovered by the OP, [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) can output the date directly to the command line:

> ```
> git log -1 123abc4 --format=%cd
> ```

If you don't want to use the stream pager (you want to print directly to the command line à la `cat`) then you can add `--no-pager` directly after the git command:

```
git --no-pager log --format=%cd -1 123abc4
```

Comment: and if I need only string containing date?

Comment: got it, `git log -1 123abc4 --format=%cd` does exactly what I need

Comment: @YawningMilk - Sweet. If you want credit for your discovery, feel free to post that as answer, leave a comment on my answer, and I'll remove the edited in quote.